# Javascript/HTML form redirects to a url path based on 2 dropdown answers (Shopify)

Tags: javascript, forms, shopify

I'm creating a product finder on my Shopify site that redirects customers to a specific path upon form submission based on their answers to 2 dropdowns, but the form submission is appending responses as search (?genre=fiction) instead of a path (/fiction/) for both answers.

Target scenario:

Dropdown 1 answer: fiction

Dropdown 2 answer: bestsellers

--> Clicking submit would take you to /fiction/bestsellers

Note that since the options are displayed in a text form "I'm looking for *fiction* books that *are bestsellers*" there's a pre-filled default scenario for "I'm looking for *any* books that *have any theme*, so the script can't just run on selection change.

Comment: It would be a good idea to provide an example of your code - like the form and you attempt to solve the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

First, you will need to get the value of both select boxes. Then using document.location.href you can redirect to any page. You can add more value in the finalURL using "+" same as this example.

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title>jQuery Redirect OnClick</title>
   </head>
<body>

<select id="first">
    <option value="fiction">fiction</option>
    <option value="fiction1">fiction1</option>
</select>

<select id="second">
    <option value="bestsellers">bestsellers</option>
    <option value="bestsellers1">bestsellers1</option>
</select>
<button  id="open_same_window">Submit</button>
 
<!-- include our library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {  
  
   $("#open_same_window").click(function(){
    var firstOption = $('#first').val();
    var secondOption = $('#second').val();
  
   var finalURL = '/' + firstOption + '/' + secondOption;
   
   alert(finalURL);
   document.location.href = finalURL;
   });
  
   
  
});
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```